# Extracting zip files in ios - making sure everything was extracted

Tags: ios, unzip

My question concerns zip files that are only partially extracted on ios:

Suppose that during extraction of a zip file, the process is interrupted such that only some of the files were actually extracted.

What is the best practice to make sure that all files were indeed extracted?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't ignore return values from I/O functions or from the zip framework. This is usually enough.
2. You can always check if the file exist after unarchiving and you can check its size.
3. You can check CRC of the extracted data.

Most zip frameworks do the 2 & 3 checks internally and they report the error transparently using a return value or `NSError` return param. Just never ignore return values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I agree with you on everything you said. However, What if the zip file extraction is stopped in the middle - for example, if the app is closed by the user. Is there a best practice way to make sure all files were indeed extracted without going through every single one of them? (for example, a zip archiver that does an "all or nothing" extraction)

Comment: @am1987 If the zip unarchiver does "all or nothing" and the user interrupts the process (e.g. by closing the app) then you should assume nothing has been extracted. If the zip unarchiver is smart, it should give you info about the progress and you can track it in a separate file and continue from the point where you stopped. However, if you want to resume unarchiving, you also have to verify that the archive wasn't changed! Usually applications don't resume interrupted unarchiving and the user is often left with partial files.